# How can I copy a selection from an unsigned char buffer into another variable and convert to int?

Tags: c++, buffer, endianness

I have an unsigned char buffer which is being read in and working fine.
I need to be able to select a number of bits within the main buffer and copy them to another variable to convert from hex data (little endian) into an integer to be displayed. I cannot for the life of me get this working. The following code prints the values I need in hex (in reverse order due to endianness) but I can't figure out how to use it.

```
void printFromBuffer(unsigned char *buffer, int block, int offset, int size){
    unsigned char *ptr = buffer;
    ptr += block * 0x10 + offset;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        printf("%X \n",ptr[i]);
    }
}

printFromBuffer(buffer, 0x08, 0x03, 0x02);
```

Thanks

Comment: Is each "block" in your buffer 16-bytes wide (i.e. these are 128-bit numbers) ? It would seem to me this would be easier to wrap your head around if the conversion function took only a buffer and byte-offset, and make the *caller* responsible for performing the block-alignment (at least initially until you understand the conversion-side better). Furthermore, if you want this to reverse the bytes so you get a real system-int, you'll need an accumulator.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this code works but, I doubt this is the most efficient way of doing this. If anyone else can clean this up to prevent future inefficiency then please go ahead.

```
void printFromBuffer(unsigned char *buffer, int block, int offset, int size, string attribute){
    unsigned char *ptr = buffer;
    char p[255];
    string contents = "";
    unsigned int x;   
    std::stringstream ss;
    ptr += block * 0x10 + offset;
    for(int i=size;i--;){
        sprintf_s(p,"%02X",ptr[i]);
        contents += p;
    }
    ss << std::hex << contents;
    ss >> x;
    cout << attribute << ": " << x;
    printf("\n");
}

printFromBuffer(buffer, 0x08, 0x03, 0x02, "Serial");
```